# How to deploy Broadleaf version 3.0.13-GA in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, broadleaf-commerce

```
I have changed `context.xml` file according to your broadleaf configuration.

I am still getting error for `entityManagerFactory`
```

I am getting this error when trying to deploy on tomcat7 standalone server.Its working perfectly in Eclipse IDE.

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo.war
912  [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [core1] webapp=null path=null params={event=firstSearcher&q=static+firstSearcher+warming+in+solrconfig.xml&distrib=false} hits=0 status=0 QTime=44
912  [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – QuerySenderListener done.
913  [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [core1] Registered new searcher Searcher@652acafc[core1] main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_315:11774:nrt _313(4.7):C36)}
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
[ WARN] 13:17:38 RuntimeEnvironmentPropertiesConfigurer - Unable to determine runtime environment, using default environment 'development'
[ERROR] 13:17:40 ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'blPersistenceUnitManager' while setting bean property 'persistenceUnitManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blPersistenceUnitManager' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blPersistenceUnitManager' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.MergePersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(MergePersistenceUnitManager.java:230)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.addTransformer(Unknown Source)
        at org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.MergePersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(MergePersistenceUnitManager.java:212)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager$Jpa2PersistenceUnitInfoDecorator.invoke(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:635)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.addTransformer(SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.java:109)
        ... 47 more
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/demo] startup failed due to previous errors
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/demo] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/demo] appears to have started a thread named [PoolCleaner[219410827:1421567252715]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/demo] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.broadleafcommerce.common.classloader.release.ThreadLocalManager$2] (value [org.broadleafcommerce.common.classloader.release.ThreadLocalManager$2@51fe6403]) and a value of type [org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.ConfigurationOnlyState] (value [org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.ConfigurationOnlyState@14582b03]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/demo] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.broadleafcommerce.common.classloader.release.ThreadLocalManager$1] (value [org.broadleafcommerce.common.classloader.release.ThreadLocalManager$1@286fdc64]) and a value of type [org.broadleafcommerce.common.classloader.release.ThreadLocalManager] (value [org.broadleafcommerce.common.classloader.release.ThreadLocalManager@47ee3df9]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory]
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory]
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory]
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8983"]
18 Jan, 2015 1:17:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15250 ms
18 Jan, 2015 1:18:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.FairBlockingQueue$FairIterator.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1587)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.FairBlockingQueue.iterator(FairBlockingQueue.java:233)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.checkIdle(ConnectionPool.java:988)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.checkIdle(ConnectionPool.java:980)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool$PoolCleaner.run(ConnectionPool.java:1348)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:534)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:484)
Exception in thread "PoolCleaner[219410827:1421567252715]" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/FairBlockingQueue$FairIterator
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.FairBlockingQueue.iterator(FairBlockingQueue.java:233)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.checkIdle(ConnectionPool.java:988)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.checkIdle(ConnectionPool.java:980)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool$PoolCleaner.run(ConnectionPool.java:1348)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:534)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:484)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.FairBlockingQueue$FairIterator
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
        ... 6 more
```

I don't know whether I have change any tomcat7 configuration files.

Anyone helps me that would be great.

Comment: This is not the full stack trace. There is more to the stack trace that is more relevant that you have left out.

Comment: INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo.war
912  [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to Tomcat's CATALINA_OPTS (on Unix this would be in set_env.sh):

```
-javaagent:/absolute/path/to/spring-instrument.jar
```

The correct version of this jar is in the `lib` directory of the DemoSite Heat Clinic.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.Those error has been cleared.but still I am not able get Demo site on Browser.No errors occurred and there is no log that server has started with port 8080 in catalina.out file.I am running solr in same tomcat also,but solr running correctly on port 8983.

Comment: Thanks a lot.finally got solution.